# react-scss : display problem of an <h1> with blur and transform, on "EDGE" only

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, microsoft-edge, display

Good morning all,

I have a display problem under "EDGE", as shown in the two photographs.
I try to simulate a shadow on a table, under CHROME everything works fine, under EDGE only half appears.
I code in "React, scss".

If you have an idea ? I tried to manipulate the height, overflow ... but nothing

in EDGE
[image edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuLxw.png)

in CHROME : It's OK
[image chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpsJE.png)

Code simple :

```
    .ombre_table{
    min-height: 5vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin-bottom: 2vh;

    text-align: center;
    
    transform: rotatex(75deg) rotateY(-2deg);
    font-size: 15vh;
    filter: blur(7px);
    

}
```

Comment: Which version of Edge browser are you using? I can reproduce the issue with Edge 86.0.622.69 with [this sample](https://jsfiddle.net/3zpjgtL7/2/). In my sample, the issue can be solved by changing the `min-height` to `height`. You can also try to change something like this in your code to move the text a little higher as a workaround. Besides, I also test in Edge Dev 88.0.692.0 and it works well so I think the issue might will be fixed in future version of Edge. You can also provide the feedback about this issue in Edge using Alt+Shift+I.

Comment: @YuZhou : thank you, for the right clues, the problem is solved. 

Comment: I'm glad to help. You can also mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on a large rotation on the Y axis, the height of the element has little influence on the placement, so I greatly increased the height size and added a top negative margin.
thanks YuZhou

```
.ombre_table{
min-height: 35vh;
width: 100vw;
margin-top: -5vh;

text-align: center;

transform: rotatex(75deg) rotateY(-2deg);
font-size: 15vh;
filter: blur(7px);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

go to 'about:flags' in edge browser and enable the filter property

Comment: thank's,but the problem it's not my browser, but my code...